# Where should data mapping occur?

Tags: node.js, rest, soap, architecture, dto

I'm building a node js application that interacts with a soap webservice. For the api the node js provides I have a rest api. For interacting with the soap webservice I have  created a separate service *soapService* to manage the interaction. In the application I have to conduct mapping between the rest api requests, and requests passed to the soap webservice. **My question is, whose responsibility is it to handle the mapping?** **I know I can have a separate mappingService, that will do the actual mapping. But, I'm interested that where the mapping by using that mappingService would happen?** Should I map the request before I pass it to the soapService, or should the soapService handle the mapping? And what about backwards? When the soapService gets a response from the actual web service, should it use the mappingService to map the request and only after that return the result to the calling api service?

I have heard about a rule that if you don't do with the mapped data anything (other than pass it a layer below), then it shouldn't be your concern at all. But on the other hand, the service below is not interested about the rest api format at all, it just wants to use the soap web service format. Because the mapping is kind of dirty work, I am allured to put it to the lower layer, so the soapService would handle the mapping. So that the higher abstraction api rest service would not have to deal with any mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The receiving service should publish an endpoint that accurately presents what it needs to perform the business logic.  If the caller stores data in a different way, it’s up to the caller to map their data into the proper format.  It would be misleading for the receiving service to publish an endpoint that conforms to the callers data structures.  What happens when you have a second caller that needs that same business logic?  You would have to create a second endpoint on the receiving system that matches the second callers specs.